# Diagonalising A Matrix without calculating its eigenvaules?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was trying to basically solve a few differential equation using a Tridiagonal Matrix, when I stumbled upon  this question.

Let's say i have a $N \times N$ tri-diagonal matrix with the three diagonal vectors a[n-1] , b[n] , c[n-1] with b as main diagonal, which is obvious from the indices.

So I have basically the matrix as

\begin{pmatrix}
     b[1] & c[1] & 0 & 0 & \cdots&0 &0 \\
     a[1] & b[2] & c[2] &0 & \cdots &0 &0 \\
     0    & a[2] &  b[3] & c[3] & \cdots&0&0 \\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots&0&0 \\
     0& 0&0&\cdots&a[n-1[&b[n-1]&c[n-1]\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0&a[n-1]    & b[n]
     \end{pmatrix}

Now I want to solve Eigen Value Problems and calculate the Eigen Values for this matrix(Using C++ and I don't want to use any predefined library)

So my first question is:

**What is the fastest way to solve Eigen-values for a Tridiagonal Matrix mathematically**

I actually used Power Method to determine Eigen-values and Eigen Vectors for a any square matrix, but the method is only to determine largest Eigen value and the corresponding Eigen-vector.

My second question is related to the first one, when I was trying to solve some differential equations using tridiagonal matrix formed from iterative formula, I was using Thomas Algorithm to solve the system, but I realize for some cases solving for Eigen Values directly would be a better and quicker method. So i thought if i could convert my matrix into a diagonal matrix it would easily provide me with Eigen Values.

To Diagonalize a matrix we use

$$D=P^{-1}AP$$

where D = Diagonalized matrix for A , $ P =  \biggl( X_1 \quad  X_2 \quad  X_3 \quad  .   .   . \quad  X_n\biggr)$
and $(X_1,X_2,X_3,...X_n)$ are all Eigen Vectors for matrix A.

This would also solve my first question . So my second question is:

**Is there any way to diagonalise a given matrix without actually calculating it's Eigen Values and the corresponding Eigen Vectors?**

Comment: "... diagonalise a given matrix without actually calculating it's eigenvalues..." - that is self-contradictory. If you've diagonalized your matrix, you've already calculated the eigenvalues, since they show up as the diagonal elements. As for your tridiagonal matrix: if the super- and subdiagonal elements have the same sign, you can perform a diagonal similarity transformation to generate a symmetric tridiagonal matrix, which is easily diagonalized by the tridiagonal QR algorithm, divide-and-conquer, MRRR, or any number of algorithms specialized to the tridiagonal eigenproblem.

Comment: When I say Diagonalize a given matrix without calculating it's Eigenvalues, what I mean is let's say I have a 3 x 3 Matrix A and I want to get a Matrix D( which would be a Diagonal Matrix) for this I would need to find out $$D=P^{-1}AP$$ 

And to calculate P I need to find out Eigenvalues from the characteristic Polynomial. 

What My question now is that: Is there any other way to Diagonalize A without having to calculate the matrix P?

Comment: This still seems a bit muddled to me. For reference: you can compute eigenvalues without eigenvectors, you *can't* compute eigenvectors without eigenvalues, and if you perform a similarity transformation with your eigenvector matrix, the original matrix is converted into a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on its diagonal. So, I don't see you being able to escape from computing eigenvalues.

Comment: Once more, I repeat the recommendation to at least look up "tridiagonal QR"; this seems the most appropriate for your situation.

Comment: Thanks I will look up for that, I will try doing that later. And I will post my result here soon!

You understood my point correctly @J.M.isnotamathematician